# convert low frequent levels of a categorical variable in "others" in R

Tags: r, dataframe, dummy-variable

I have a categorical variable that I want to convert into dummies for a classification task. the problem is that some of the levels appear just a few times, thus they create problems of perfect-multicollinearity when I split my sample in training set and testing set.

How can I get rid of these levels in a quick and elegant way? 
Here is a simple example of the my data:

```
label   var_x
 1        1
 0        2
 1        1
 0        3
 1        2
 0        4
 0        5
 1        5
 1        1
 ....
```

Let's say that I want to keep only the levels that appear more than 1 (or any other number)
I want to recode as "0" those cases and obtain something like this:

```
label   var_x
 1        1
 0        2
 1        1
 0        0
 1        2
 0        0
 0        5
 1        5
 1        1
 ....
```

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One `dplyr` option could be:

```
df %>%
 add_count(var_x) %>%
 mutate(var_x = as.numeric(n > 1)*var_x) %>%
 select(-n)

  label var_x
  <int> <dbl>
1     1     1
2     0     2
3     1     1
4     0     0
5     1     2
6     0     0
7     0     5
8     1     5
9     1     1
```

And the same idea with `base R`:

```
as.numeric(with(data.frame(table(df$var_x)), Freq[match(df$var, Var1)]) > 1)*df$var_x
```

Comment: it gives me this error: Error in select(., -n) : unused argument (-n)

Comment: Try `dplyr::select(-n)`.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need this one :

```
 mtcars %>% 
   mutate(cyl_factor = forcats::fct_lump(as_factor(cyl),prop=.4),
          disp_factor = forcats::fct_lump_min(as_factor(disp), min = 2)) %>% 
   head(10)

    mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb cyl_factor disp_factor
1  21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4      Other         160
2  21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4      Other         160
3  22.8   4 108.0  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1      Other       Other
4  21.4   6 258.0 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1      Other       Other
5  18.7   8 360.0 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2          8         360
6  18.1   6 225.0 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1      Other       Other
7  14.3   8 360.0 245 3.21 3.570 15.84  0  0    3    4          8         360
8  24.4   4 146.7  62 3.69 3.190 20.00  1  0    4    2      Other       Other
9  22.8   4 140.8  95 3.92 3.150 22.90  1  0    4    2      Other       Other
10 19.2   6 167.6 123 3.92 3.440 18.30  1  0    4    4      Other       167.6
```